# Send Coupon Data using Google Tag Manager

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am trying to use google tag manager for Ecommerce tracking.

Seems like all is working fine except the coupon code.
No data related to coupon is sent during the tracking.

Here's the code:-

```
window.dataLayer.push({
                'event': 'transactionComplete',
               'transactionId': data.orderNumber,
               'transactionCurrency': 'USD',
               'transactionAffiliation': 'Booking confirmation',
               'transactionTax': '0',
               'transactionShipping': '0',
               'transactionTotal': data.grandTotal,
               'transactionPromoCode': couponCode,
               // 'currencyCode': 'INR',
               'transactionProducts': [{
                   'id': data.propertyId || "",
                    'name': data.propertyName,
                    'category': data.city,
                    'price': data.grandTotal,
                    'coupon':couponCode,
                    'quantity': quantity,
                    'sku': ''
               }]
            });
```

Any Idea ?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6107169?hl=en), unfortunately GTM does not support promo codes for standard ecommerce tracking.

Answer (score 1):

You could always drop the `transactionPromoCode` in a custom dimension with [product-level scope](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828?hl=en#example-product).

[image]

Then just create a Data Layer Variable for `transactionPromoCode`.

[image]

Comment: +1, and if that promocode gives you a discount on the price you might create a product level custom metric to go along with it that holds the discount value.